# Android Studio doesn't see my ZTE Blade III device

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I got my first Android smartphone - **ZTE Blade III** and want to start learning it. I've downloaded Android Studio for Windows, created basic "Hello World" app, tried to run it on the phone and here I encountered a problem - Adroid Studio doesn't see my device.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P74Rm.jpg

I followed [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice). I installed ZTE USB driver, enabled USB debugging on my phone and set targetSdkVersion to match Android version of device (I have Android 4.0.4, so I set it to 15), but Android Studio still doesn't see the device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried 'adb devices' from the command-line to see if adb itself can see the device?

Comment: Running 'adb devices' returned "List of devices attached" and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to enable Windows Update and set Windows auto driver download function to always on, like in this guide: http://zteblade3.com/zte-blade-3-install-a-custom-jelly-bean-rom-ics-rom-from-scratch/install-the-usb-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened up the: /path/to/android/sdk/tools/android Android SDK download tool and installed "Google USB Driver" under the "Extras" folder? (Required for Windows. Screenshot from Linux computer)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I installed Google USB Driver.